# Stuck in integration

Tags: integration

Integrate :
$$\int_{1}^{\tfrac{1+\sqrt5}{2}} \frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1} \ln\left(1+x-\frac{1}{x}\right)\,\mathrm dx.$$

My try : [image]

But unable to proceed further

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Let $t=1+x-\dfrac1x$, so that $dt=\left(1+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)dx$.

$$\int\frac{x^2+1}{x^4-x^2+1}\log\left(1+x-\frac1x\right)dt=\int\frac{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}{x^2-1+\dfrac1{x^2}}\log\left(t\right)dx=\int\frac{\log(t)\,dt}{t^2-2t+2}.$$

The new integration bounds are $1$ and $2$, so the integral can be written

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log(u+1)}{u^2+1}du=\frac\pi4\log2-\int_0^1\frac{\arctan u}{u+1}du.$$

Comment: To terminate the computation, use the change of variable $y=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$